# SBT won't resolve fakehttpserver dependency because of bad commons pom file

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to use this [fake http server](https://bitbucket.org/jideji/fakehttpserver/wiki/Home) project in a sbt 0.11.0 based project.  Unfortunately one of it's dependencies is giving the following error:

```
[error]     public: bad organisation found in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.pom: expected='org.apache.commons' found='commons-io'
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.commons#commons-io;1.3.2: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descriptor file found in 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.pom': bad organisation: expected='org.apache.commons' found='commons-io'; 
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/home/project_location/}default-db401d/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.commons#commons-io;1.3.2: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descriptor file found in 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.pom': bad organisation: expected='org.apache.commons' found='commons-io';
```

From what I can tell this can be worked around by asking that ivy not check the consistency of the pom files (Maven has this setting off by default).  I can't work out how to turn this off in sbt though.  I tried

```
ivyValidate := false
```

but this has no effect.

Am I on the right track with this setting and is it possible to turn this setting off?

Answer (score 3):

You could try to exclude this dependency and include it manually :

```
"se.dannej" % "fakehttpserver" % "0.1.0" exclude("org.apache.commons", "commons-io")

"commons-io" % "commons-io" % "another version"
```

or even download the `commons-io` jar and push it in your `lib` directory.